# iOS: How to get all pod names in Podfile in a ruby script or shell script?

Tags: ios, ruby, cocoapods

`target_names = installer.pod_targets.map { |target| target.name }`in post_install can get all dependent pods, but it include sub pod of pod in Podfile.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the answer,below code in `post_install` can do it.

```
podfile = Pod::Podfile.from_file(Pathname.new('Podfile'))
  podfile_pod_items = podfile.dependencies.map do |pod|
      pod.name
  end
```